# Can meeting of the minds be premised on a dialog with an agent even though terms are accepted on a webpage?

Tags: contract-law, england-and-wales, air-travel, refund, meeting-of-the-minds

Bob missed his flight from London Stansted, which he explained upon arriving at the airport to staff of an airline by its check in counter. The employee tells him his options for the order departures for his destination throughout the rest of the day, including one leaving purportedly from the same airport they are standing in in three hours time, which would, the employee advises, leave him ample time to check in etc., and it would cost £42. Bob agrees that given this it would be a good option, and the employee starts working on his computer terminal to book it for Bob, but then looks back up at Bob and explained that because it was already less than 3.5 hours before departure, he would be unable to book it for Bob on his terminal and Bob would therefore need to use his mobile device to book it for himself. Bob goes to Google flights, searched for flights from London to his required destination, sees one flight with the same airline listed for £41.49 at precisely the time that the employee had reported the flight as being at, from London to his required city, and books it on his mobile device, assuming that it simply must be the one that the check in counter staff was referring to. He’s then milling about with a couple of hours to kill and goes to open the airline’s website to conduct an online check in, when he notices that in fact the flight at 12:05 which he booked was from London Gatwick and not from London Stansted, where he was. He turns back to the check in counter to ask what this is about and the man who “sold” him the flight is gone, apparently gone to the boarding gates to charge people for excess baggage. But his supervisor is there and tells Bob that if he hurries on down to Gatwick, he might just barely make it.

Bob wants to know what the discrepancy was caused by, if it was that he had booked the wrong flight or if a 12:05 departure to his destination even existed from Stansted. The manager explains that there had been a flight but it finished the prior day so he must have been looking at the old schedule but then goes back to urging him to hurry to Gatwick because he may still make it.

Upon reaching Gatwick, but missing the flight, he complains to the airline staff there before being told that all refund requests are processed by the website and they are processed based on where the mistake was made: if the man behind the check in counter had booked Bob onto the wrong flight then a refund would have to be granted, while if it was Bob booking himself in on his own device, and simply not noticing the exact departure airport for the flight he was about to book, then it would not be so granted because the mistake would be presumed to be Bob’s own.

Does the fact that the initial understanding and meeting of the minds was formed through dialogue with the airline’s employee, itself on the basis of understanding that Bob required assistance due to his brain running on not even three hours of sleep, and furthermore being panicked by the scramble to catch the flight, not figure at all into the issues?

Answer (score 5):

### No

As described, Bob and the agent clearly did not have anything like a meeting of the minds necessary to form a contract. In fact, the agent explicitly said they could not accept the booking.

Furthermore, once a contract has been reduced to writing (as it was when Bob accepted the terms on the webpage), any pre-contract discussions are inadmissible. Bob accepted the terms offered for the flight Bob booked (without the agent's assistance, it seems), so that's that.

Nor is that agent's misstatement actionable. It's not reasonably foreseeable that misstating there was a flight from London Stanstead would induce a reasonable person to book a flight from London Gatwick. The airline is not responsible for Bob's misunderstanding, lack of sleep, panic, or the confusing way London chose to name its airports.

Comment: No, not in my reading of it: first the agent pointed out the fact of the flight and it having available seats, explicitly *offering* to book it for Bob. Bob then contemplates and *accepts* the offer, before the agent attempts to book it on his terminal before realising that it is not possible at that point in time to do so, apologising for the inconvenience, and explaining to Bob that he would unfortunately have to book it on his own device. So are your sure about that?

Comment: And I’d think it would certainly at least be arguably reasonably foreseeable if the search interfaces presented the full name of the city in much larger print than the airport codes implicated by the flight.

Comment: do you still stand by your answer given the second scenario that I edited it to add?

Comment: @Seekinganswers yes, because I rolled back your edit. We don’t allow edits that invalidate existing answers. If you want something else answered, ask another question

Comment: on what basis do “we” not allow such edits, particularly when they better clarify the original intent of the question? Adding further examples of a scenario to better pinpoint its conceptual essence is not wanting something else answered but testing the applicability of the principle of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Restatement of facts

Bob misses a flight and talks to a booking agent at Stansted about a replacement flight.

The booking agent says he can't help him, Bob needs to book himself with the app.

Bob books a flight without further assistance and without reading properly that his flight starts in Gatwick. As a result, Bob does nothing to get to the correct airport.

Bob claims the agent did something wrong and wastes more time by demanding the agent's manager. Bob promptly misses the second flight.

### Was there a contract?

Yes, there was a contract between Bob and the Airline, **facilitated by an online service.**

#### What were the terms of the contract?

When Bob booked the replacement flight while standing in Stanford, using the online service, he requested and agreed to **a flight from Gatwick at 12:05 for 41.99**. The terms further stipulated when he should be at which gate (boarding time), as well as the typical Terms of Service for the airline, as well as the service provider that facilitated the booking.

#### Does the agent play any role?

The talk with the agent did neither modify the contract, as that was before Bob booked any flight via a different service provider, nor did any conduct of the agent in any way indicate that they were at all offering a contract with Bob. In fact, the agent explicitly stated, that he could not offer assistance or booking for a specific flight from Stanford, so he explicitly denied forming any contract with Bob through his position as an Agent.

Pointing him to a different service provider that might be able to offer a booking does not form any contract. **It is a clear sign that the agent did not form any contract and that there was no meeting of the minds.**

#### Who's on the hook?

The doctrine [**Caveat Emptor**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caveat_emptor) applies: if you book a flight ticket, it is your responsibility to understand where you need to be when to take the flight, and decide if that is a suitable flight.

If the agent **had** facilitated the booking, he'd have informed Bob of such facts, but Bob booked the flight via some other service, so the agent is not liable or even a party to the contract formation.

As long as the facilitating platform clearly labels the flight as starting at LGW/EGKK, it is up to Bob to understand that the flight requires him to cross the town, when he is currently at SFB/KSFB.

The portal Bob used to book the flight most likely did provide the required information, and Bob just didn't read the language properly, thus Bob is the only entity that is legally the reason he missed his second flight.

#### Bot wants to know...

> Bob wants to know what the discrepancy was caused by, if it was that he had booked the wrong flight or if a 12:05 departure to his destination even existed from Stansted.

Legally, there is no discrepancy: The contract via the booking platform stipulates he booked the [wrong] flight for 12:05 from Gatwick, and from a legal standpoint it is irrelevant if Stansted has or ever had or will have a 12:05 flight to the same or any other destination.